# Databrick pyspark Error While getting Excel data from my Azure Blob Storage

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to read an excel file with multiple sheets in my Blob storage Azure Gen2 using Databrick pyspark. I already install the maven package.
Below my code :

```
df = spark.read.format('com.crealytics.spark.excel') \
.option("header", "true") \
.option("useHeader", "true") \
.option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \
.option("inferSchema", "true") \
.option("sheetName", "sheet1") \
.option("maxRowsInMemory", 10) \
.load(file_path)
```

Running this code I get this error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o323.load.
> : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader$
> at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:22)
> at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:13)
> at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:8)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:390)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:444)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:400)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:400)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:287)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you attached the library to a cluster?

Comment: Hello @AlexOtt, yes I already attached the library to a cluster and Notebook.

Comment: is it compiled for correct version of Scala that matches DBR version?

Comment: @AlexOtt in order to be sure I install both Scala2.11 and Scala2.12, and is not work. My DBR version"9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)".

Comment: You should remove version for 2.11

Comment: Were you able to solve it ?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT, Not yet. I use panda as alternative solution, but I hope solve this issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you verify if you have properly Mount an Azure Blob storage container.

Checkout official MS doc: [Access Azure Blob storage using the RDD API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-blob-storage-using-the-rdd-api)

> Hadoop configuration options are not accessible via SparkContext. If
> you are using the RDD API to read from Azure Blob storage, you must
> set the Hadoop credential configuration properties as Spark
> configuration options when you create the cluster, adding the
> spark.hadoop. prefix to the corresponding Hadoop configuration keys to
> propagate them to the Hadoop configurations that are used for your RDD
> jobs

Configure an account access key:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net <storage-account-access-key>
```